# run command sudo apt-get upgrade failed in Rasperry Pi 4

Tags: upgrade

When I run command: sudo apt-get upgrade, I got the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

> ```
> Reading changelogs... Done
> Setting up libc-bin (2.28-10+rpi1) ...
> Aborted
> ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf: No such file or directory
> ldconfig: Path `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf' given more than once
> ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf' given more than once
> /opt/vc/lib:
>   libvcos.so -> libvcos.so
>          ...
>   libBrokenLocale.so.1 -> libBrokenLocale-2.28.so
> ldconfig: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.28.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring
>
>   ld-linux-armhf.so.3 -> ld-2.28.so
>          ...
>   libcom_err.so.2 -> libcom_err.so.2.1
> /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:
> Aborted
> dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
>  installed libc-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 134
> Errors were encountered while processing:
>  libc-bin
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
> ```

I have tried clean and remove and upgrade again still have the same error.
I am not sure how to fix it, anybody has any suggestion to fix it? Thanks.